# How to publish the angular universal application after using @ng-toolkit/universal; working fine on local, which folders to push on IIS server

Tags: angular, iis, publish, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

There are multiple folders in dist folder which folder to put on deployment server, the folder contents are following:
browser folder,
server folder,
server.js,
prerender.js

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when you run build:prod it generates the server.ts file, this file has configuration for Dist folder path const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'somePath');this path could be dist/browser or whatever you want, when you place your publish on IIS, make sure it matches it, I just placed my dist folder contents in browser folder, rather than putting it in the root directory,and server.js in the root directory i.e
Root-Directory-IIS/dist/browser.
p.s to deploy angular universal on IIS we need iisnode to handle server.js file as it is node.js application and also url-rewrite.